# How does spring know which view resolver to use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently reading [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) and I am trying to configure a view resolver in spring, however the book didn't say "How spring chooses which View Resolver to use" Its describer to configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver`  and how to add prefix and suffix. But, I could't not find how spring chooses which Resolver to use. What tell spring which resolver to use ?

Edited: 
quote from the book :

"" What’s missing here is how Spring knows about Tiles definitions. By itself, Tiles-
ViewResolver doesn’t know anything about any Tiles definitions, but instead relies on
a TilesConfigurer to keep track of that information. So we’ll need to add a Tiles-
Configurer bean to spitter-servlet.xml:



/WEB-INF/viewsviews.xml


 ""

The book never answered the question it asked: "how Spring knows about Tiles definitions"

Comment: Nothing. The `DispatcherServlet` consults all `ViewResolver`s in the application context until one of them returns a view.

Comment: The order specified or depending on the `order` attribute if defined. However if you have a `UrlBasedViewResolver` as first in your view resolver chain the others will not be consulted. an `UrlBasedViewResolver` simply creates a URL and forwards to that URL. It doesn't check if that URL actually results in a view to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view resolvers implements **org.springframework.core.Ordered** interface, spring will order the resolvers according to this interface.

PS: `TilesViewResolver` from tiles2 or tiles3 packages are extends `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

Comment: @Adio, correct, if you are using different view resolvers, you need to notice the orders.

Answer (score 3):

Look at property "order". But remember: "ONLY ONE InternalResourceViewResolver CAN EXIST IN CONTEXT, NO MORE"

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="prefix" value="${view.prefix}" />
        <property name="suffix" value="${view.suffix}" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: So the order is the key ?

Comment: You can specify for each view resolver order property. Its define which resolver will be called firstly, which will be second and etc...

Answer (score 1):

The `TilesViewResolver` is a specific `ViewResolver` for Apache Tiles that happens to need extra configuration in order to perform it's operation.

The extra information that it needs is the `TilesConfigurer`. That bean contains the information about the Tiles definitions and can be configured for example like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/viewsviews.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As is mentioned by section 16.5.2 of the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-viewresolver-chaining):

> Spring supports multiple view resolvers. Thus you can chain resolvers
>   and, for example, override specific views in certain circumstances.
>   You chain view resolvers by adding more than one resolver to your
>   application context and, if necessary, by setting the order property
>   to specify ordering. Remember, the higher the order property, the
>   later the view resolver is positioned in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to define a **ViewResolver**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

If you don't declare any ViewResolver implementation in your application context, Springs registers one for you by default.
The default is an automatically-registered **InternalResourceViewResolver**.

If you declare your own view resolver(s), then the default **InternalResourceViewResolver** will not be used. If there are multiple view resolvers, then they will be consulted in order until one of them returns a view object.

Answer (score 0):

**InternalResourceViewResolver** class inherite from **UrlBasedViewResolver** where you can find this. After you define bean for view resolver your view resolver maps your url,from where farther request for view will process

```
   public void setAttributesMap(Map<String, ?> attributes) {
        if (attributes != null) {
            this.staticAttributes.putAll(attributes);
        }
    }
public Map<String, Object> getAttributesMap() {
        return this.staticAttributes;
}
```